# TextField's in UITableView resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have a UITableView with CustomCells which contain a TextField.  Look at the pictures which i have uploaded.

[Picture1](http://i44.tinypic.com/amaxli.jpg) [Picture2](http://i39.tinypic.com/so3e45.jpg)
I want that if i start to scroll the keyboard should hide.

I tried it with

```
  - (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   NSLog(@"Got called");
   ProductTableCell *cell;
   [cell.mengeTextField  resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Console-Log:

```
2012-04-24 12:57:48.924 Book-App[21029:15803] Got called
2012-04-24 12:57:50.535 Book-App[21029:15803] Got called
2012-04-24 12:57:51.681 Book-App[21029:15803] Got called
```

But this is not working for me.

Is there a other solution?

Comment: is that method getting called or not?Put a console log and check is it called?

Comment: Yes the Method is getting called. I edited my Post with the Log

Comment: did you connect outlet for each textfield in your UITableView??

Comment: Yes i connect a outlet for the textfield. Its a dynamic TableView

Comment: If you connected the outlet means you dont need to declare "cell" in this method.You just [myTextField resignFirstResponder]; do like this

Comment: i cant call just [textField resignFirstResponder]; because like i set in my Question. I have a CustomCell. The textfield is declared in the customCell so i tried to set a property in my TableViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is what Arcank said, cell is not defined.

```
- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   NSLog(@"Got called");
   ProductTableCell *cell;// <---this cell is nil
   [cell.mengeTextField  resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Now if you cannot access the cell, there is a way to cheat. Simply put something else a first responder, then resign it right away.

```
- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
       NSLog(@"Got called");
       [scrollView becomeFirstResponder];
       [scrollView resignFirstResponder];//You might not even need this (not sure)
    }
```

This would take care of your problem. If scrollView cannot become first responder just use other things that can. (improvise).

---

Edit: Just read you and Aalok Parikh comments, this is pretty much what he is trying to say.

Comment: Thx. I found also a other solution to solve this. I used  [[self.tableView superview] endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 1):

use this method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` this will solve your problem

Comment: Do you mean like that? - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(ProduktTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; 
{
     [cell.menge resignFirstResponder];
} I tried but also did not work

Comment: not exactly like that you can use `becomeFirstResponder` to give the focus to any other controll

Comment: if i do that, my keyboard is always shown. I want that if i load the view the keyboard is hidden. If i hit the textfield the keyboard should appear, so i can put something in it. Now, if i start to scroll, the keyboard should disappear.

Comment: use other control not textfield

Answer (score 0):

In your code, cell never gets set. It's nil. So the -resignFirstResponder message has no effect.

Comment: How can i call the cell in the scrollViewWillBeginDragging method?

Answer (score 0):

implement this method
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
}

Comment: This does not get called unless the textField is done being edited. Which to my knowledge does not happen when you scroll a view.